# Python: (Seaborn?) heat map from irregular meshgrid

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

Lets say that I have two given meshgrids (e.g. measured data):

- grid_1 ranges from `x=(-10...10); y=(-10...10)` with a step size of 1
- grid_2 ranges from `x=(-30...-10) & x=(10...30);
  y=(-30...-10) & y=(10...30)` with a step size of 5, so it has a hole of
  the size of grid_1
- I also have z-values (`'dose'`) for every pair of `xi, yi` for both meshgrids
  and both datasets are present as tables with the three columns `x, y, dose`

I tried to draw a heat map representation of this data using seaborn's heatmap() function:

```
dm1 = df1.pivot('y', 'x', 'dose')
opts = {'cmap': 'YlGnBu_r'}
ax = sns.heatmap(dm1, **opts)
ax.invert_yaxis()
plt.savefig('dosemap-test-smooth.pdf')
```

[image: dosemap-smooth]

```
dm2 = df2.pivot('y', 'x', 'dose')
ax = sns.heatmap(dm2, **opts)
ax.invert_yaxis()
plt.savefig('dosemap-test-coarse.pdf')
```

[image: dosemap-coarse]

```
df = df1.append(df2)
dm = df.pivot('y', 'x', 'dose')
ax = sns.heatmap(dm2, **opts)
ax.invert_yaxis()
plt.savefig('dosemap-test-total.pdf')
```

[image: dosemap-total]

Drawing the two meshgrids independent from one another works just fine, but drawing them together some breaks the binning(?) of the heatmap.
So my question is: How can I achieve to draw a heatmap(-like) representation of this 'irregularly' distributed data using python? :)

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Can you provide example data?

Comment: I think I would look into the scipy interpolation tools which can help you resample your datasets onto the same grid.

Comment: @IanS: The two data samples can be found [here](http://pastebin.com/deE mz02D) and [here](http://pastebin.com/vp76AmwQ). @mwaskom: Could you point me to which tools of `scipy.interp` I could use for this? Because I ran into some troubles using `interp2d()` and `griddata()